# Unable to remove a class containing controls for userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform I am creating with VBA, in Excel. I have a row that contains about 10 combo boxes and 5 text boxes. The data and selections entered into these boxes are used for other calculations elsewhere. The user can add as many additional rows as are needed, when a new row is created the class creates the controls during initialization and adds them to the userform. All the events are handled in the class for the instance too.

The above works perfectly as far as I have tested (although there may be a better way of going about this). The problem I have is when I try to delete any of the rows that are added. I have a button on the userform and I have tried several different ways but to no avail (I also tried searching this issue but haven't found anything specific enough to my problem to help). The controls.remove method doesn't seem to work (even though the controls are all added at runtime). I tried different versions by putting the code in the class and others where it is in the userform.

For some additional info, I have a global collection created on the userform where I add my rowClass objects. In this class I create and add all the boxes mentioned above and name them depending on the order they are added.

I'm thinking that I need to change the structure of the code so that all the buttons are added from the userform and the events remain in the class (the combo boxes need to function the same but be independent of the other rows). I would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to remove a control from a userform is:

```
Me.Controls.Remove sControlName
```

Where sControlName is a string variable containing the name of the control